# how can I change asp.net core 6 wwwroot folder path to another server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, wwwroot

I'm facing this situation, the customer wants to set the  IIS on server , SQL Server on other server and uploaded files on other server.
all servers linked in local network , IIS server connected to the internet only.

so how can I change asp.net core 6 wwwroot folder path to another server?

I tried to set shortcut of a network folder in the wwwroot but it's look like a .link not a folder

Comment: You don't really want to do that... that is only where the pages/routing would be....  SQL server just requires changing the connection string... for storing files you'd just copy them to the UNC path (careful here... keep permissions limited...)  Though I may have misunderstood?  This statement is sort of contradictory: "all servers linked in local network , IIS server connected to the internet only."

Comment: @pcalkins you can check my last edit on  the question

Comment: Nice.  Still I wouldn't serve files directly like that.  Let the back-end serve the file in the response.  (so you can be sure to check authorization, and/or prevent "deep-links")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to solved this issue add:

```
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("\\\\192.168.1.234\\Arc\\Uploaded\\"),
     
});
```

this work fine in debug mode, in publish gives this error:

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

to solve it add account in IIS:

1. Open the IIS Management
2. Open the Application Pools ->Select the application pool you want
   to change
3. Right click the application pool and select Advanced Settings
4. Select the Identity list item and click the ellipsis (the button
   with the three dots)
5. Select the custom account -> set...
6. insert user name: <machinename>  and related password
7. ok , ok ,ok ...

[image: Steps to add account]